# Error trying to upload an image using dropbox library in python

Tags: python, dropbox, image-upload

Trying to create a program that takes an image from a local path if it exists and uploads it to Dropbox. This is part of the Code:

```
 if os.walk(local_file_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(local_file_path, img_name)
            dest_path = os.path.join('/photos', img_name)
            with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                
                dbx.files_upload(f.read(), dest_path, mute=True)
```

This is the error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\tensor\network\untitled10.py", line 53, in <module>
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), dest_path, mute=True)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\dropbox\base.py", line 2964, in files_upload
    f,

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox.py", line 338, in request
    user_message_locale)

ApiError: ApiError('56376ca00bfc465b8a0a6c55a626a583', UploadError('path', UploadWriteFailed(reason=WriteError('malformed_path', None), upload_session_id='AAAAAAAAAId17KDB4XpN4g')))
```

Comment: A `malformed_path` error should indicate that your `dest_path` value isn't valid for a Dropbox path. What is the exact value of your `dest_path` variable?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I've used the /photos path in the past to create a script that downloads images and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The destination path should be written:

```
    dest_path = os.path.join('/photos/', img_name)
```